# Post to twitter with curl (in shell) without using the developer api

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to post tweets with a script in shell(linux) without using the API keys. I have thought of curl saving the cookies but I don't have the knowledge to perform this script. I don't mind if it uses twitter.com or mobile.twitter.com

```
 #!/bin/bash

 user=$1
 pass=$2
 #read -p $'Tweet: ' tweet

 cookie="$user.cookie"
 useragent="Mozilla/5.0"

 init=$(curl -s -b $cookie -c $cookie -A "$useragent" "https://mobile.twitter.com/session/new")
 tok=`echo "$init" | grep "authenticity_token" | sed -e 's/.*value="//' | sed -e 's/" \/>.*//' | tail -n 1`

 login=$(curl -s -b $cookie -c $cookie -A "$useragent" -d "authenticity_token=$tok&username=$user&password=$pass" "https://mobile.twitter.com/session")
```

EDIT: Add code

Comment: Using a combination of `--cookie` and `--cookie-jar` you should be able to accomplish this, but you need to show some work that we can help with as we're not generally in the business of writing code from scratch for people.

Comment: I edited to add the login code, but I don't know if its working